# SceneKit load dae as subclass of SCNNode

Tags: swift, scenekit

I would like to load object from dae file to variable that is a subclass of SCNNode. File contains model and animations. I have a function to load model as SCNNode, but I don't know how to change it to use SCNNode subclass.

```
extension SCNNode {
    class func loadModel(named fileName: String) -> SCNNode? {
        let modelFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "dae")!
        let sceneSource  = SCNSceneSource(url: modelFileURL, options: [SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption.animationImportPolicy : SCNSceneSource.AnimationImportPolicy.playRepeatedly])
        return sceneSource?.entryWithIdentifier("MDL_Obj", withClass: SCNNode.self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to subclass SCNNode? This is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I have encouraged weird error, where after I load dae animation with textures, and then remove this node, textures are not deallocated, and there is a memory leak. I have found similar thread on forum about it, and it seems to be an SceneKit error. What they suggest to do is to set all first material properties to nil when removing node. In my case I can't do this while removing  node, because I'm keeping this node in few places to reuse later. I was thinking about reseting to nil these variables in deinit of SCNNode subclass. Worked even without it, just using this wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works, but still needs to verify with more examples:

```
class Model3D: SCNNode {

    init?(modelName: String) {
        guard let scnNode = SCNNode.loadModel(named: modelName) else { return nil }
        super.init()
        geometry = scnNode.geometry
        position = scnNode.position
        scnNode.childNodes.forEach {
            addChildNode($0)
        }
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```